# How I can change some symbols on my Locale?

Tags: xubuntu, 14.10, locale

I use Xubuntu 14.10 and bg_BG locale. But I want to use dot instead comma for decimal separator in some apps like LibreOffice, Galculator, etc.. I want to change default group separator in CSV files comma to semicolon.
How I can edit bg_BG locale table to make this?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a line to your `~/.profile` file to change a single locale category. For instance, adding this line:

```
export LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
```

would make dot the decimal separator the next time you log in, since that's the convention in the US.

As regards CSV files, it sounds like a question for respective programming language, and not related to the locale.